# ¿Como alinear verticalmente un ImageView dentro de un Toolbar por medio de codigo java?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragment, android-imageview

** Esta es la imagen que deseo centrar verticalmente dentro de mi Toolbar por medio de codigos en java ya que estoy usando el colapsingToolbar, alguien sabe como le hago?**

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    android:id="@+id/img_photo_profile"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/image_width"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/image_heigth"
    android:src="@color/white"
    app:border_width="2dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="-1"
    app:layout_behavior="com.woogpyme.www.chatiemos.Sections.CircleImageBehavior"
    app:startHeight="2dp"
    app:startToolbarPosition="2dp"
    app:startXPosition="2dp"
    app:border_color="@android:color/white"
    app:finalHeight="@dimen/image_final_width"
    />
```

Answer (score 0):

Pruébalo añadiéndolos en un `Realative Layout` y luego podrás utilizar la propiedad `android:layout_centerVertical="true"`.

Comment: Ya lo intente pero no quedo como esperaba.... Asi que obutuve el alto del toolbar y el alto de la imagen y los dividi ps y ya quedo.